# show that u(x, t) = $e^{At}$ + B$e^{-3t}$cos(x) + C$e^{Dt}$ cos(2x)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> The temperature $u(x,t)$ of a copper wire of length $\pi$ obeys the one-dimensional heat equation
> $$
> u_t = 3u_{xx}
> $$
> in the domain $0 < x < \pi$ for all $t > 0$, with the initial condition
> $$
> u(x,0) = 1 − \cos(2x), quad \text{ for } 0 < x < \pi.
> $$
> (a) Suppose the temperature $u(x,t)$ also satisfies the boundary conditions
> $$
> u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi, t) = 0, \quad \text{for } t \ge 0.
> $$
> By substitution or otherwise, show that
> $$
> u(x, t) = e^{At} + Be^{-3t}\cos(x) + Ce^{Dt}\cos(2x)
> $$
> is a solution to the heat equation satisfying the initial and boundary conditions for appropriate values of the constants $A, B, C$ and $D$.

So far I have identified that I have to use Neumann boundary conditions and have
$$
\begin{split}
A_0 &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^L f(x)dx
     = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi (1-\cos(2x))dx 
     = 2\\
A_n &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^L f(x)\cos(\frac{nx\pi}{L})dx \\
    &= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi (1-\cos(2x))\cos(nx)dx \\
    &= \frac{2}{\pi} \times \frac{4\sin(n\pi)}{n^3-4n} \\
    &= 0
\end{split}
$$
as n must be an integer and for all integers of n, so $\sin(n\pi)=0$.

I know I have gone wrong somewhere and am not sure if it is my whole approach or if I have messed up somewhere can anyone please help.

feel free to edit tags if I have this in the wrong place and sorry this is so poorly written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, likely the simplest one, is to substitute directly into the PDE and note that if
$$
u(x, t) = e^{At} + Be^{-3t}\cos(x) + Ce^{Dt}\cos(2x)
$$
then
$$
u_t = Ae^{At} -3Be^{-3t}\cos x + DCe^{Dt}\cos(2x)
$$
and
$$
u_{xx} = -Be^{-3t}\cos x-4Ce^{Dt}\cos(2x)
$$
so you can solve for $A,B,C,D$ which make $u_t=3u_{xx}$ hold.

**UPDATE**

So $u_t=3u_{xx}$ implies we have
$$
\require{cancel}
Ae^{At} -\cancel{3Be^{-3t}\cos x} + DCe^{Dt}\cos(2x) 
= - \cancel{3Be^{-3t}\cos x} - 12Ce^{Dt}\cos(2x)
$$
and we must have $A=0,D=-12$ with any values for $B,C$.

Comment: OK so I am getting A=0 and B=0 , c=-1 and D = -12 is this right if not can you show what I got wrong. I also just want to say thank you so much for all the help so far your editing and answers have been so amazingly helpful.

Comment: How do i solve for A, B, C and D

Comment: @sufferingmathsstudent close but not quite. Please see my update